# Java regex checking for special characters always returns true

Tags: java, android, regex

No matter what I pass through this function, everything is true.

```
asd -> should be false
asd123 -> should be false
asd 123 -> should be false
asd_123 -> should be false
asd-123 -> should be false
asd asd -> should be false
```

Any other special char should return true.

```
public static boolean checkSpecialChars(String word) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9 -_]+", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher matcher;
    matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
    boolean checker = matcher.find();

    if (checker) { return true; }
    return false;
}
```

What am I missing on this?

Comment: try ```Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9 -_]+", Pattern.MULTILINE);``` .

Comment: Your question is not clear at all e.g. `asd` does not have a special character; then why should it return `false`? Do you mean, it should return `true` for any characters other than `a, s, d, 1, 2, 3, -, and _`?

Comment: Also: `find()` finds subsequences. If you want to match entire input, use `matches()`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash those are example. I want to only include 'a-zA-Z0-9 -_' and no matter what i try, its true. meaning there are special characters.

Comment: @letsCode - In that case, you should replace the whole body of your function with just one statement, `return !Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(word).matches();`

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few problems here:

- `-` in a character class creates a *range* of characters, so  `-_` unintentionally includes every ASCII character between space and `_`, which includes most "special characters" on the keyboard (not all, though).  You need to escape it with a backslash (`\\` because the backslash itself needs to be escaped in Java as well).
- `Matcher.find()` checks if any substring matches, not the entire string. You want `Matcher.matches()`
- Your conditional is reversed.  If you want it to return true if there *are* special chars, it should reverse your check.

It's not quite true that *any* string matches with the current code—`{}` doesn't, for instance—but it's certainly broader than intended.

Fixed code:

```java
  public static boolean checkSpecialChars(String word) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9 \\-_]+", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher matcher;
    matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
    boolean checker = matcher.matches();

    return !checker;
  }
```